# How to detect new entries in Core Data store without having to query every x milliseconds?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, ios7, fifo

1. **Batch retrieval:** I have a stream of unique data - user IDs - coming from the server in batches.
2. **GET request operation:** I then have to send GET network requests individually for each of these user IDs (the server end point will only handle one user at a time).

To ensure that no data is lost during the batch retrieval and GET request operation I have a thought of saving the data stream of user ID batches in a persistent store using Core Data.

I then want to create a `FIFO_UsersStillNeedingToBeSentToServerSingleton` class that would handle both the saving and retrieval of data stored in the persistent store. Any user id that is saved must instantly ping a GET network request to the server and upon succesful callback will be deleted from the persistent store moving onto the next user id.

Problem:
How can I avoid having to ping the persistent store for any user entries every x milliseconds?

Ideally:
I would like for there to be a way for my singleton class to be notified when there is data in my FIFO stack and so to then carry out the necessary GET request operation.

Comment: Core Data is probably overkill - especially where multiple threads are involved.  Have a read through the iOS Concurrency programming guide - it has methods for synchronising activities such as these

Comment: why would Core Data be overkill? I'm only using its persistent store to quickly save the user ids incase an application crashes. So rather than saving a huge array once the process is done, I am saving those small batches as they come; and while these batches arrive multiple GET requests would need to be sent concurrently using AFNetworking. I see no harm in using Core Data for the persistence, no?

Comment: I meant for a task queue.

Comment: I don't understand what it is that you're trying to tell me now @Paulw11. Upon reading my last comment does your previous comment still stand? 
p.s. thanks for taking a look, Paul.

Comment: Pavan, let me know if my answer needs any clarification.

Comment: I just thought that managing the multithreading complexities of Core Data to persist transient data, like a task queue, is probably excessive when there are much lighter-weight techniques available from GCD. It will probably work though

Answer (score 0):

In your singleton, you can implement an [NSFetchedResultsController](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/index.html) and [NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate). Your delegate method
controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath will be called when the underlining data changes. No need to write polling code just to find out when the data change.

Alternatively, you could listen for NSNotificationCenter NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification and other core data related notifications in your singleton. Actually, this might be a simpler code to implement if I understand your needs fully.

In any case, either of above suggestions can work.